# Ошибка в WPF С# Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем привет, начинаю писать приложения на WPF. Возникла, мне кажется детская проблема, но не могу исправить.

> System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

ChangelogText было null.

XAML код

```
<UserControl x:Class="AndroidRomTool.Views.Control.AboutControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AndroidRomTool.Views"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="548" d:DesignWidth="1010" >
<Grid Background="#EFEFF1">
                <RichTextBox x:Name="ChangelogText" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="280" Margin="25,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="955">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Text="Beta Version"/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>

</Grid>
```

С# Код

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace AndroidRomTool.Views.Control
{
       /// <summary>
      /// Логика взаимодействия для AboutControl.xaml
       /// </summary>
       public partial class AboutControl : UserControl
      {

    public AboutControl()
    {
        LoadChangelog();

        InitializeComponent();

    }
    public void LoadChangelog()
    {
        string fileName = "text.txt";

        TextRange range;

        FileStream fStream;

        if (File.Exists(fileName))

        {

            range = new TextRange(ChangelogText.Document.ContentStart, ChangelogText.Document.ContentEnd);

            fStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

            range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Text);

            fStream.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Можете помочь.

Comment: В какой строке выдаёт ошибку? Что такое ChangelogText.Document и откуда оно берётся? Вероятнее всего вы пытаетесь обратиться к ContentStart или ContentEnd - но у вас Document = null (и ошибка в коде который вы не привели)

Comment: range = new TextRange(ChangelogText.Document.ContentStart, ChangelogText.Document.ContentEnd); на этой

Comment: из логики это всё), я уверен проблема в usercontrol

Comment: @MrIkso Ошибка действительно детская. Ответьте, из за чего происходят такие ошибки?

Comment: То есть код вы добавлять не будете? Из текущего ничего не сказать о том, как исправить ошибку.

Comment: ну есть ещё родительский код разметки интерфейса, без логики, @ EvgeniyZ ошибка возникает при попытке обратится в ричтекстбоксу

Comment: Я вообще имею ввиду, что эта ошибка означает, вы знаете? Мне интересно понять, знаете ли вы ее суть или нет.

Comment: прочитал в сети пару статей,  но сути так и не понял

Comment: Эта ошибка возникает тогда, когда вы обращаетесь к тому, что еще не инициализировано. То есть `MyClass test = null; test.Prop = 1;` выдаст ошибку, ибо `test` будет не инициализирован. Теперь перейдем к вашей проблеме, как думаете, когда в WPF приложении инициализируются все XAML объекты? Я дам вам подсказку, это всегда есть в конструкторе окна, запуск такого маааленького метода...

Comment: решилось), не там вызов был прописан,   InitializeComponent();
            LoadChangelog(); , так заработало

Comment: Думайте всегда логически, не бегите сразу гуглить и спрашивать. Мой вам совет...

Comment: спасибо за совет. Это я вечером уже не совсем хорошо думаю), забываю самое простое